# Logistic regression and complementary log log model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multiple-regression, logistic, diagnostic

Is there like a diagnostic checking (like those in the time series) done for logistic regression and complementary loglog model?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many diagnostic checks done in these situations.  Any textbook on generalized linear models should introduce them to you.  A lot of them are adaptions of those used in the linear regression case eg plotting residuals to see if they have the distribution expected in the model; plotting residuals against explanatory variables or candidate explanatory variables to see if there is structure that is not explained by the model; etc.  Checking for autocorrelation in the residuals would certainly be one thing that should be done if they are a time series.